# PostgreSQL drop function executes given function and doesn't remove trigger function

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, postgis

I created the trigger function with the below code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION snitch() RETURNS event_trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    select pgr_createTopology('public.roads_noded', 0.001);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER snitch ON ddl_command_start EXECUTE FUNCTION snitch();
```

It is located in the public schema. Now I want to drop this function but when I try to drop it executes the given function and the server hangs. After restarting the server, the same thing happens. I can't create or drop any table. Is there a way to remove this trigger function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DROP FUNCTION` command is itself a DDL command so the trigger will fire. You should first remove the trigger using `DROP EVENT TRIGGER`, then the function.

Comment: thanks for the response, I tried `DROP TRIGGER snitch` but it requires a table name. This is an event trigger and not assigned to any table, so, it gives an error without a table name.

Comment: The command should be `DROP EVENT TRIGGER`. Answer updated